# My Nokia 2.1 not appearing on my list of emulator device in android studio

Tags: android-studio, nokia-e-series

My Nokia 2.1 is not showing on list of emulator on my Android studio.i tried installing ADB driver but it still not showing. I need help guys

Comment: But it's not an emulator, it's an actual phone. Also, did you enable ADB on the phone?

Comment: I developed an application using android studio and i want to test it using my Nokia phone. But the  phone isnt appearing on the list of devices. Please how do i turn on my ADB on the phone

Answer (score 1):

As a security feature, ADB is blocked by default. In order to fix this, you must enable USB Debugging in Settings > Developer options > USB Debugging. After you do that, plug in your phone and you should be prompted to trust a computer, after you answer the dialogs on your phone, run "adb devices" on that computer, if your device appears, ADB works!